# Reference for OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient

Tags: c#, facebook

I am trying to use below piece of code in class library for facebook authentication.

I am unsure what dll needs to be referenced?   I could not find [Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157864(v=vs.111).aspx) in references.

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
        appId: "",
        appSecret: "");
```

Comment: Adding a link to the documentation makes it easer for others to also check the documentation.

Comment: @DaImTo, Yes that is great